# Парсер сайта аптек

Tags: python, парсер

Создал небольшой парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://apteka.ru/vendor/Эгис%20Фармацевтический%20завод%20ЗАО/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36',
           'accept': '*/*'}
HOST = 'https://apteka.ru'

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return  r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='catalog-card card-flex')

    lp = []
    for item in items:
        count = item.find('span', class_='light-button__label').get_text(strip=True)
        if count == 'Купить':
            lp.append({
                'name': item.find('a', class_='catalog-card__name').get_text(strip=True),
                'vendor': item.find('span', class_='emphasis').get_text(strip=True),
                'price': item.find('span', class_='moneyprice__roubles').get_text(strip=True),
                'currency': item.find('span', class_='moneyprice__currency').get_text(strip=True),
                'link': HOST + item.find('a').get('href')
            })
        else:
            lp.append({
                'link': HOST + item.find('a').get('href')
            })
    return lp

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        lp = get_content(html.text)
        print(lp)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

**Вопросы:**

1. на сайте если `count = 'Купить'` - значит только одна дозировка, иначе есть выбор. Тогда в массив `lp` я помещаю только `link`. Нужно во время работы `get_content(html)` вызывать по `link` дополнительный вызов или проверять после `parse()`, когда массив `lp` будет уже сформирован? И как правильнее будет вставить в тот же массив?
2. как обойти все страницы, а не только первую?

**UPDATE:**

1. ненужный вопрос, поменял структуру, намного лучше теперь и быстрее
2. обход исполнил следующим образом (на странице появляется новый класс, если на ней нет карточек товара):

```
def parse():
    i = 1
    LP = []
    # Для каждой страницы
    while get_html(URL, {'page': i}).status_code == 200:
        html = get_html(URL, {'page': i})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
        page = soup.find('div', class_='catalog-empty-response')

        # Остановка в случае пустой витрины на странице
        if page:
            break
        else:
            lp = get_content(html.text)
            LP = LP + lp
            i = i + 1
    print(LP)
```

Comment: 2. А вы смотрели в инспекторе браузера на вкладке Сети какой запрос формируется для следующих страниц? :)

Comment: @gil9red, пока не дошёл до этого, спросил заранее. Сейчас переделываю структуру, немного не так выдало. Но у меня **мини-вопрос:** на сайте выдаёт результаты наличия в зависимости от города. В парсере не указывается, но результат схож с моим местоположением. Получается если запустить код в другой точке мира, то будет другой результат?

Comment: все может быть:) поэтому, если будете запускать на vds, проверьте внимательно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как обойти все страницы, а не только первую?

есть три подхода:

1. сформировать все возможные ссылки, выкачать. Но это не всегда возможно.
2. качать рекурсивно. Когда получили новую ссылку, то просто вызываем функцию "скачивания страницы". Если страниц и вложенности немного, то вполне работает и легко кодируется.
3. списочный способ. Схематический код

   ```
    urls_to_download = ["http://start_url"]
    downloaded_urls = [] # может лучше set?
    while urls_to_download не пустой:
      #извлечь один url  с списка urls_to_download 
      url = urls_to_download.pop()
      if url in downloaded_urls:
        continue
      new_urls = download(url)
      # добавить new_urls  в urls_to_download 
      urls_to_download = urls_to_download  + new_urls
      #добавить url  в список downloaded_urls 
      downloaded_urls.append(url)

    def download(url):
      #скачиваем и парсим страницу.
      page = get(url)
      #сохраняем в базу/диск
      save_page(page);
      #возвращаем список спарсеных с страницы ссылок
      return extract_urls(page)
   ```

Comment: Страниц немного, всё зависит от выбранного города, если через браузер смотреть

Comment: `set` будет лучше, constant lookup - мощная штука

Comment: а он на самом деле константный? но если в списке 10 элементов, то оно не особо и важно

Comment: @0dminnimda, я обошел понятным мне способом. Обновление сделал в вопрос

Comment: @KoVadim, я обошел понятным мне способом. Обновление сделал в вопрос

Comment: @KoVadim не уверен на счёт [set_lookkey](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/21fa8547921d28b80b8a88d034081cab000d5480/Objects/setobject.c#L56-L57), но все остальные функции, участвующие в `key in set` - O(1)

Comment: ага, потому что там хешмапа. Да, тогда в  большинстве случаев там будет близко к константе. Нормально.

Comment: @KoVadim, да и это было бы очень глупо, если бы `set` не имел бы constant lookup-а, это везде так (да и тем более в этом фишка `set`-а)

Comment: я лично ожидал логарифма.